# Angular watch factory value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Say i have the following factory:

```
app.factory("categoryFactory", function (api, $http, $q) {    
    var selected = null;
    var categoryList = [];
    return {
        getList: function () {
            var d = $q.defer();
            if(categoryList.length  <= 0){
                $http.get(api.getUrl('categoryStructure', null))
                    .success(function (response) {
                        categoryList = response;
                        d.resolve(categoryList);
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                d.resolve(categoryList)
            }
            return d.promise;
        },
        setSelected: function (category) {
            selected = category;
        },
        getSelected: function () {
            return selected;
        }
    }    
});
```

now i have two controllers using this factory at the same time. Because of this both controllers has to be notified when updated for this i attempted the following:

```
    app.controller('DashboardController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$log', 'Session', 'api','categoryFactory', function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $log, Session, api, categoryFactory) {

    $scope.selectedCategory = categoryFactory.getSelected();

}]);
```

While my other controller looks like this:

```
    app.controller('NavController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$log', 'Session', 'api', 'FileUploader', 'categoryFactory', function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $log, Session, api, FileUploader, categoryFactory) {
    $scope.categories = [];

    categoryFactory.getList().then(function (response) {
        $scope.categories = response;
    });
    $scope.selectCategory = function (category) {
        categoryFactory.setSelected(category);
    }

}]);
```

how ever when the `NavController` changed the value it was not changed in the `DashboardController`

My question is how can i either `watch` or in another way get notified when the value changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `observer` pattern, like so:

```
app.factory("categoryFactory", function (api, $http, $q) {   
    // the list of callbacks to call when something changes
    var observerCallbacks = []; 

    // ...

    function notifyObservers() {
        angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function(callback) {
            callback();
        });
    }

    return {
        setSelected: function (category) {
            selected = category;
            // notify the observers after you change the value
            notifyObservers();
        },
        registerObserver: function(callback) {
            observerCallbacks.push(callback);
        }
    }    
});
```

And then in your controllers:

```
app.controller('NavController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$log', 'Session', 'api', 'FileUploader', 'categoryFactory', function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $log, Session, api, FileUploader, categoryFactory) {
    // ...

    // init
    (function() {
        categoryFactory.registerObserver(function() {
            categoryFactory.getList().then(function (response) {
                $scope.categories = response;
            });
        });
    })();

}]);
```

This way, any time `setSelected` is called, it calls each callback that you've registered in `observerCallbacks`.  You can register these from any controller since factories are singletons and they will always be in the know.

*Edit:* just want to add that I may have put the `notifyObservers()` call in the wrong area (currently in `setSelected`) and that I may be putting the wrong update call in the controller (currently `getList`) but the architecture remains the same.  In the `registerObserver`, put whatever you want to do when the values are updated and wherever you make changes that you want observers to know about call `notifyObservers()`

Comment: Hey tom worked like a charm however you need to remove "this" from your registerObserver function

Comment: Great Answer! Just FYI: an additional $scope.$apply() call was neccessary in my case to get my variables to update! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could follow [**dot rule**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) here so that prototypal inheritance will get followed.

Basically you need to have one object inside your service that will have `selected` variable, And will get rid of `getSelected` method.

**Factory**

```
app.factory("categoryFactory", function(api, $http, $q) {
    var categoryFactory = {};
    categoryFactory.getList = function() {
        var d = $q.defer();
        if (categoryList.length <= 0) {
            $http.get(api.getUrl('categoryStructure', null))
                .success(function(response) {
                    categoryList = response;
                    d.resolve(categoryList);
                });
        } else {
            d.resolve(categoryList)
        }
        return d.promise;
    }
    categoryFactory.setSelected = function(category) {
        categoryFactory.data.selected = category;
    }
    categoryFactory.data = {
        selected: null
    }
    return categoryFactory;
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('DashboardController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$log', 'Session', 'api', 'categoryFactory',
    function($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $log, Session, api, categoryFactory) {
        //this will provide you binding without watcher
        $scope.selection = categoryFactory.data;
    }
]);
```

And then use `{{selection.selected}}` on html part will update a value when changes will occur in selection.

Comment: hey mate thank you for your answer. Sadly it does not seem to work :S the value is not changed in the controller once the value is changed in the factory